# iOS App Archive Submission failed with errors though version numbers are correct and higher than previous one

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My previous approved version was 1.0.1 and I am trying to submit new version with version number 2.0.1.

***ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “101” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number."***

***ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [2.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [101]."***

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My previous approved version was 1.0.1

I don't think so. The error message is clear, and is at variance with the claims you make in your question. Notice that it says nothing about "1.0.1". *You* talk (in your question) about "1.0.1", but iTunesConnect says "101". I believe iTunesConnect, not you.

Clearly, then, you blew it and submitted a version "101". Well, "2.0.1" is less than "101", because it is parsed as a version string, and "2" is less than "101".

Comment: @matt Thanks, I had a similar issue in Phonegap where I thought my version 2.1.0 was 'higher' than my previous version 1.9.999 but Apple measure things differently! I also has to use a version without dots in my config file... <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString"><string>21000</string></gap:config-file>